# Typescript can't find/import modules from within a ts file one level up from tsconfig.json

Tags: node.js, json, typescript

My directory structure is essentially this:

**Main/project-root/*** (tsconfig.json, packages.json, app.ts, etc are here)
**Main/shared/*** (shared.ts is here along with other ts files, no packages.json or anything else)

Here's an example **project-root/app.ts** file:

```
import * as yup from 'yup'
import { whatever } from '@shared/shared.ts'

//do stuff

export default myexports;
```

Here's an example **shared/shared.ts** file:

```
import * as yup from 'yup'

//shared stuff

export default mysharedexports;
```

app.ts is fine, the issue lies with shared.ts. It can't resolve the 'yup' module.

In my project-root/ is where I have the `yup` validation module installed. There's no packages.json or anything other than .ts files inside shared/* directory.

Here's my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "@quasar/app-vite/tsconfig-preset",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": ["../shared/*"],
      "@synced-validation/*": ["src/validation/*"],
      "src/*": ["src/*"],
      "app/*": ["*"],
      "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "layouts/*": ["src/layouts/*"],
      "pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
      "assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
      "boot/*": ["src/boot/*"],
      "stores/*": ["src/stores/*"],
      "validation/*": ["src/validation/*"],
    },
  }
}
```

Here's `@quasar/app-vite/tsconfig-preset` json in case you need it (default vite).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    // `baseUrl` must be placed on the extending configuration in devland, or paths won't be recognized
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    // Needed to address https://github.com/quasarframework/app-extension-typescript/issues/36
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    // Avoid cross-os errors due to inconsistent file casing
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    // Fix Volar issue https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1153
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"],
      "app/*": ["*"],
      "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "layouts/*": ["src/layouts/*"],
      "pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
      "assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
      "boot/*": ["src/boot/*"],
      "stores/*": ["src/stores/*"]
    }
  },
  // Needed to avoid files copied into 'dist' folder (e.g. a `.d.ts` file inside `src-ssr` folder)
  // to be evaluated by TS when their original files has been updated
  "exclude": ["dist", ".quasar", "node_modules"]
}
```

My expectation is that the shared.ts should have access to all the same node_modules that app.ts has access to. I've tried adding `"rootDirs": ["./", "../shared"]` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr;** I'd give shared a package.json or use workspaces if your use case calls for it.

---

As it stands, the 'shared' directory can be considered a separate project in its own right, it doesnt know about the sibling 'project-root' directory.

The solution to me depends on how you want to treat 'shared' moving forward.

If 'shared' is to be used by many different projects, then treat it as a library, providing it with it's own package.json and other relevant files. Give it everything it needs to do its job.

If 'shared' is to be used solely in the context of one project, let's say its part of a monorepo of a few child projects, then I'd look at using workspaces to manage each package in the monorepo and their dependencies.

- npm: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces
- yarn: https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces

The following is based on yarn being the package manager.

Your project structure in the monorepo could then look like this:

> - /mono-repo-root/
> - /mono-repo-root/package.json
> - /mono-repo-root/node_modules

> - /mono-repo-root/apps/your-app-A/
> - /mono-repo-root/apps/your-app-A/package.json

> - /mono-repo-root/libs/shared/
> - /mono-repo-root/libs/shared/package.json

The package.json in the mono-repo-root will then have a section specifying the relevant workspaces:

```
  "workspaces": [
   "apps/*",
   "libs/*"
  ],
```

From here, any time you add new apps to the 'apps' directory or new libs to the libs directory, all you'll need to do is an install to link things together.

When it comes to using a lib inside one of your apps, you'll need to add it as a dependancy inside that apps package.json

This looks a little like:

```
"dependencies": {
   "shared": "portal:../../libs/shared"
}
```

If going down the monorepo approach, there will be other setup required to keep things running smooothly (tsConfigs for instance, I've got one per package, but you may be able to simplify this).

Comment: Good option breakdown, thanks. I ended up doing a root level package.json until I feel a need to upgrade to yarn workspaces.